# Retrieve related models using hasManyThrough on a pivot table - Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to retrieve related models of the same type on from a pivot table.

I have 2 models, `App\Models\User` and `App\Models\Group` and a pivot model `App\Pivots\GroupUser`

My tables are have the following structure

users

- id

groups

- id

group_user

- id
- user_id
- group_id

I have currently defined relationships as

In app/Models/User.php

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class)->using(GroupUser::class);
}
```

In app/Models/Group.php

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->using(GroupUser::class);
}
```

In app/Pivots/GroupUser.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
}
```

I'm trying to define a relationship in my `User` class to access all other users that are related by being in the same group. Calling it `friends`. So far I've tried this:

app/Models/User.php

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        User::class,
        GroupUser::class,
        'user_id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

But it just ends up returning a collection with only the user I called the relationship from. (same as running `collect($this);`

I have a solution that does work but is not ideal.

app/Models/User.php

```
public function friends()
{
    $friends = collect();
    foreach($this->groups as $group) {
        foreach($group->users as $user) {
            if($friends->where('id', $user->id)->count() === 0) {
                $friends->push($user);
            }
        }
    }

    return $friends;
}
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this using `hasManyThrough` or some other Eloquent function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that using `hasManyThrough` because there is no foreign key on the `users` table to relate it to the `id` of the `group_user` table. You could try going from the user to their groups to their friends using the existing `belongsToMany` relations:

app/Models/User.php:

```
// create a custom attribute accessor
public function getFriendsAttribute()
{
    $friends = $this->groups()                                          // query to groups
                    ->with(['users' => function($query) {               // eager-load users from groups
                        $query->where('users.id', '!=', $this->id);     // filter out current user, specify users.id to prevent ambiguity
                    }])->get()
                    ->pluck('users')->flatten();                        // massage the collection to get just the users

    return $friends;
}
```

Then when you call `$user->friends` you will get the collection of users who are in the same groups as the current user.